# Does the work of internal forces vanish?

Tags: forces, work

[image]

Just to be sure: the text doesn't say that $\sum_{i,j}\int_1^2 F_{ji}\cdot ds_i$ vanishes, does it? If we consider the pair 
$$ 
\int_1^2 F_{ij}ds_j+\int_1^2 F_{ji}ds_i, 
$$ 
then sure we can say $F_{ij}=-F_{ji}$, but what about the distance traveled by the particles? That could be different right (we don't necessarily have $\Delta s_i=\Delta s_j)$, so the terms don't cancel out?

I'm confused because they split the sum in these two separate sums, but they don't do anything with it. Either this second term vanishes or not, and I would think it doesn't. Is the reason I gave above the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the text doesn't say that the second integral vanishes and it shouldn't either because it is this term that is responsible for the change in potential energy of the system.

For example, consider two bodies moving towards each other due to gravity. If we consider these two bodies to form the system under consideration then external forces are zero and

$$W_{12} = \int_1^2 F_{12}ds_2+\int_1^2 F_{21}ds_1, $$ 
$$=\int_1^2Fds$$
since $F_{12} = - F_{21} = F$ (say) and where ds is their relative displacement. And mow you can see clearly that this is the change in potential energy of the system.

What this means is the familiar principle that the change in potential energy of the system equals the change in kinetic energy of the system (in case of zero work due to external forces).

Comment: And yes your reason is right: the displacements are not equal in general even if the forces are equal and opposite and hence the work integrals don't cancel.

Comment: Oh, first I didn't see why $\int_1^2 F_{12}ds_2-\int_1^2 F_{12}ds_1=\int_1^2 Fds$, but of course we can consider the relative displacement. Thank you, that was a very clear answer!

Comment: @AbhijeetMelkani So internal forces can produce work right?

Comment: The work by one internal force is cancelled out by the work of the equal and opposite internal force which means the total work done on the system by the internal forces is zero.